# Populate a Listview with 2 columns from text file c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Super noob question. Sorry...very new to C# WPF. I would like to split this txt. file into 2 columns in a list view.[TxT File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvqY6.png)[Listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrlC7.png). So HostName: will land under "Item" and the actual host name will fall under "Details" and so forth with the rest of the file. I Think i need to split the string into and array and then foreach, lost at this point...help.

Comment: You need to write a class for the row items and put instances of it in an ObservableCollection bound to the ListView's ItemsSource property. Search Stack Overflow for WPF ListView ObservableCollection and you'll find examples. The search feature here is worthless, so use Google.

Comment: Thanks...I will take a look.